# issue in C with read after epoll_wait in a pthread

Tags: c, pthreads, gpio, epoll

I am working on a MQTT client app in C for an Embedded ARM system that must send message base on GPIO change.

To do this, I have try to launch a `pthread` that do a `epoll_wait` and a `read` on `/sys/class/gpio/gpio<x>/value` to get the value on change.

First step is the configuration of the gpio as input and edge as both:

```
root@ad:~# cat /sys/class/gpio/gpio13/direction
in
root@ad:~# cat /sys/class/gpio/gpio13/edge
both
```

Second step, is the start of the pthread in the main function. (After running the prthread, main will enter in a loop to manage MQTT communication):

```
// Main
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    Network n;
    MQTTClient c;
(...)

    toStop = false;
    
    pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, detection, NULL);
        
    while (!toStop)
    {
        MQTTYield(&c, 100);

        (...MQTT stuff...)
    }
    
    
    // stop thread if exists
    if(thread_id)
    {
        pthread_cancel(thread_id);
        
        thread_id = NULL;
    }

(...)
}
```

Then the pthread run the following function:

```
// detection function call as pthread
void *detection(void *args){

    char strvalue[1];
    int ret;
    int nn;
    int ep;
    int fd;

    struct epoll_event ev, events;

    
    ep = epoll_create1(0);
    
    fd = open("/sys/class/gpio/gpio13/value", O_RDONLY);
    
    nn = read(fd, &strvalue, 1);
    
    if (nn > 0) {
        printf("Initial value = %c\n", strvalue[0]);
        lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
    }
    
    ev.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLET; // EPOLLPRI;
    ev.data.fd = fd;


    ret = epoll_ctl(ep, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, fd, &ev);
    printf("ret=%d\n", ret);
    
    while (1)
    {
        printf("Waiting\n");
        
        ret = epoll_wait(ep, &events, 1, -1);
        printf("ret=%d\n", ret);
        
        if(ret > 0) {
            lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
            printf("fd=%d\n", events.data.fd);

            nn = read(events.data.fd, &strvalue, 1);
            printf("nn=%d\n", nn);
            
            printf("value = %c\n", strvalue[0]);
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

The problem is that when gpio change, epoll_wait got it, but the thread stop during `read`

Here are the output:

```
Initial value = 1
ret=0
Waiting
ret=1
fd=7
nn=1
value = 1
Waiting
ret=-1
Waiting
ret=1
fd=7
```

If I call the function `*detection` directely in the main (so without pthread), everything is working well.

How to solve this issue ?

Comment: Unrelated: You could make your code cleaner by making `strvalue` a `char` instead of an array of one `char`. You could than write `strvalue` instead of `strvalue[0]` and `read(fd, &strvalue, 1);` would be correct

Comment: thank you for the advice. ```strvalue``` was an array of 4 chars at the beginning, I reduce to 1 for testing purpose.

Comment: You're welcome. When it is an array, you should not take the address of the array when using with `read` etc. It'll decay into a pointer to the first element so `read(fd, strvalue, 4);` would be the proper call, not `read(fd, &strvalue, 4);`

Comment: What if use `EPOLLPRI` only, without `EPOLLIN | EPOLLET` ?

Comment: Switch to use `libgpiod` which has already support for monitoring the events.

Comment: @dimich same issue with `EPOLLPRI`.

Comment: @0andriy I am cross compiling for an [OpenIPC](https://openipc.org/) linux kernel (```arm-openipc-linux-musleabi-gcc```) where libgpiod is not natively available. I have cross-compilation errors with this library, so before more investigation in this direction, I will try solving the code proposed.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, for files in sysfs it's even better to read entire page, i.e. 4096 bytes.

Comment: @dimich _"it's even better to read entire page"_ - Better than using the proper pointer type when calling functions? I'm sorry, but I don't understand the correlation or if those two are supposed to be mutually exclusive.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I mean we don't know how much data will be transferred by kernel on `read()` call. It may be 1 byte, may be 4, may be more.

Comment: @dimich I haven't even made a comment related to that. I merely suggested using the proper types when doing whatever OP aimed to do.

Comment: @TedLyngmo You mentioned `read(fd, strvalue, 4);` in the comment, so i though you mean to read 4 bytes instead of 1. Sorry, nevermind.

Comment: @dimich I see. That was to make it clear to OP who stated (in the comment above mine) _"`strvalue` was an array of 4 chars at the beginning"_ that the proper way to call `read` in that case would have been `read(fd, strvalue, 4);`, not `read(fd, &strvalue, 4);`

Comment: @dirandad Did you try to use `poll()` instead of `epoll()`? `poll()` behavior is well documented for sysfs GPIO interface.

Comment: Finally solve by... renaming ```thread_id``` variable in ```gpiothread_id```. An other pthread usage in another included c file was using the same name... The strange thing is that compiler don't give any warning for a duplicated name... Well 2 nights of investiguation for that.... Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: Why not reading the `libgpiod` source code and see how it's done there?

Answer (score 1):

Specific issue. `thread_id` variable name was already used in an other c code included, but compiler dont warning it.